# Erreur dans l'agencement des propositions d'une phrase

Tags: grammaire, sens, linguistique

> Il avait une courte barbe blanche, un grand nez, et ses yeux gris foncés, ronds et pleins d'une profonde bonté étaient ombragés par des sourcils blancs.

Voilà une phrase correcte, qui soit dit accessoirement est tirée de *Via Mala*, de john Knittel, fait n'ayant aucune incidence dans la présente question. Si on remplace le possessif « ses » par un article indéfini, ce n'est plus une phrase correcte.

> Il avait une courte barbe blanche, un grand nez, et DES yeux gris foncés, ronds et pleins d'une profonde bonté étaient ombragés par des sourcils blancs.

Est-ce une phrase qui reste grammaticale ? À quel niveau de l'analyse de la phrase (grammatical, syntaxique, sémantique,…) se trouve la faute ? Existe-t-il  un nom pour cette sorte d'erreur ?

La recherche dans ce domaine ne produit rien parce que c'est une question très théorique, bien qu'en termes de la compréhension approximative de la phrase qui la suggère, sans identifier les principes, c'est une question qui n'est que rarement un problème pour le scripteur.

Answer (score 2):

On peut décomposer la première phrase en :

- Il avait une courte barbe blanche, un grand nez.
- Ses yeux gris foncés, ronds et pleins d'une profonde bonté étaient ombragés par des sourcils blancs.

Avec la deuxième phrase, cela donne :

- Il avait une courte barbe blanche, un grand nez et des yeux gris foncés, ronds et pleins d'une profonde bonté.
- étaient ombragés par des sourcils blancs.

Si la première partie de la deuxième phrase est ok, ce n'est pas le cas de la suite où il manque le sujet du verbe ("étaient"). Il s'agit là d'un problème de syntaxe.

Comment: Je serais ennuyé de corriger ce que je crois être quelques fautes dans votre texte pour m'apercevoir que je n'ai pas compris certaines choses ; êtes vous sûr de l'arrangement final de vos mots (mis à part les mots collés les uns aux autres) ?

Comment: @LPH : merci, j'ai corrigé l'erreur de copier/coller.

Answer (score 0):

Je peux lire la phrase avec l'article défini de deux manières distinctes. Tout d'abord par ellipse du pronom relatif *qui* (*des yeux qui étaient ombragés par des sourcils blancs*). Deuxièmement sans ellipse et dans ce cas je comprends un style descriptif qui s'éloigne de l'anatomie de la personne pour rendre autonomes les yeux et leurs caractéristiques. Alors que dans le premier cas l'ellipse rappelle un *oubli* ou une *inadéquation* [syntaxique](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/52715) et que le sens n'est guère différent de la phrase originale, dans le deuxième cas l'effet est différent à mes... yeux. Je préfère faire une analyse qui maximise les possibilités d'expression qu'une lecture qui les réduit et j'accepte donc cette deuxième interprétation comme valable, quoique proposant sur un *procédé* particulier. J'appelle généralement cette « erreur » *liberté*.

Comment: Je ne crois pas que l'on puisse justifier l'existence d'une ellipse. Néanmoins, votre conclusion est que la seconde phrase aussi est correcte, et que c'est une coordination de deux propositions selon les normes usuelles. (Évidemment, il existe un nombre important de ces normes que je ne connais pas moi-même précisément.)

Comment: @lph La réponse est peu étayée et plutôt subjective. Je ne trouve pas la phrase insuffisante au point de dire qu'elle est erronée. La formulation me fait penser à des yeux comme des créatures, je ne sais trop comment dire.

Comment: Je pense mon commentaire approprié en cela que je ne trouve aucune référence qui montre qu'une ellipse doive être prise en compte (cette question d'ellipse est importante, d'ailleurs il n'y aurait pas d'ellipse possible en français, seulement des omissions de répétition, et encore pas dans tous les cas).